# Move one Git repo into a subfolder of another with branches

Tags: git, merge

I have a Git repo `Old` that I want to move into a subfolder `sub` of an existing Git repo `New`. I have two branches, `master` and `feature`, within `Old` that I want transferred over as well; `Old\master` should just merge into `New\master`, and there should be a new branch in `New` called `old-feature`.

I'm not overly concerned about clean history; my current process is to just do a `git mv` in `Old` before doing the migrations, and that's fine with me. I prefer to avoid rewriting history, if possible.

My current migration steps are as follows (in the `New` repo):

- `git remote add -f old ...`
- Create new `old-feature` branch from `master`.
- Create local `feature` branch from `old/feature`.
- Merge branch `feature` -> `old-feature`.
- Merge branch `old/master` -> `master`.
- Push both branches.

While this works, I find that later if I merge from `old-feature` to `master`, Git is not understanding the history (I mean my messed-up history) and treats the every file as a merge conflict. How do I do a proper migration maintaining the branch relationships?

Comment: What do you do with the `git mv` in `old`? E.g. are you moving all the files and directories from `Old` into `Old\sub`?

Comment: Do the two repos have any common commits to start?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Yes, now I'm moving them into `sub` while they're still in `Old`, and then doing the migration. The two repositories do not have anything in common.

Answer (score 0):

While this belongs in a long comment not an answer, I wanted to show you the result that I achieved by following your process with two separate repos, so that I could ask how the example log below is unsatisfactory. (Note: I only had one merge conflict which was for the `README.md` file in both repos.)

PowerShell

```
> cd Old
> git commit --allow-empty -m "A commit from Old"
> dir -Exclude sub | % { Move-Item $_ sub }
> git add -A; git commit -m "Move all to sub"
> cd ..\New
> git remote add old -f <full-path-to-Old>
> git checkout master
> git checkout -b old-feature
> git branch feature old/feature
> git merge feature
> git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate -20
```

Log Result

```
*   4b636e7 (HEAD, master) Merge remote-tracking branch 'old/master'
|\
| * 4aa5741 (old/master) Move all to sub
| * 158c921 Commit from old/master.
| * c258979 Commit from old/master.
| * b00b001 Commit from old/master.
| * b0b582b Commit from old/master.
| * b6487e1 Commit from old/master.
| * 15b676a Commit from old/master.
| * 9db62a7 Commit from old/master.
| * 1ff5856 Commit from old/master.
| | *   f8475cb (old-feature) Merge
| | |\
| |/ /
|/| |
| | * 54e0f30 (old/feature, feature) Commit from old/feature.
| | * 999e6b5 Commit from old/feature.
* | | f0dd795 (origin/master) Commit from new/master.
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you want to "maintain branch relationships." What would you like to change about the history illustrated in my example?